# Windows10: how do delete .DS_STORE files via powershell/command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-10

so I searched the net for various ways to delete OS X files (.DS_STORE and ._.DS_STORE) files on my Windows machine.

Things I've tried (1st and 2nd options where things I found in the internet)

**first option** - using powershell + dir/remove-item combo

```
dir D:\my-stuff\ -include "._*",".DS*" -Recurse -Force | remove-item

It finds the files but gives an error

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemUnAuthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
remove-item : Cannot remove item D:\my-stuff\._.DS_Store: You do not have sufficient access rights to perform this operation.

 I then went to my drive properties and then security to give my user full control. Still the same results.
```

**second option** - using powershell + get-childitem/remove-item combo

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter .DS_STORE | Remove-Item -WhatIf

which didn't result in any files being found.

Also tried

Get-ChildItem -recurse -filter .DS_STORE

and still didn't any files
```

**third option** - using command prompt/del command this time

```
D:\>del /f /s .DS_STORE ._*
Could Not Find D:\.DS_STORE
```

Comment: seems like on the third option your not in the dir with the `.DS_STORE` file

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel I know but I want to do the find in the root folder and delete the file recursively

Comment: of course  the command will only work on the root folder where the file is and not otherwise

Answer (score 8):

First `cd` to the folder where there is `.DS_STORE` file

```
cd D:\my-stuff
```

Then run below command for deleting file called `.DS_Store` recursively

```
del /s /q /f /a .DS_STORE
```

or this one below for deleting other hidden file matching the wildcard `._` which for some reason you should be carefull since there might be other files you gonna need that match the wilcard

```
del /s /q /f /a:h ._*
```

Comment: Confirming this is the easiest way to achieve the job

Comment: just comment, those commands only works if you are using classic terminal, not in Windows Shell